# What is the distribution of dark energy?

Tags: dark-energy

Dark matter is not distributed evenly. It forms clouds, it concentrates in galaxies, it forms [hairs](https://www.nasa.gov/feature/jpl/earth-might-have-hairy-dark-matter) around celestial bodies.

A google search for dark energy distribution floods me with dark matter distribution results.

How is dark energy distributed? Does it cover the space uniformly, at even density, or does it create areas of concentration or other irregular forms?

Comment: The problem with describing the distribution of dark energy is that the only way we "know" it exists is because our universe's expansion is accelerating. Unlike dark matter, where we can measure its effects in numerous ways, we have no real good way of measuring detailed information about dark energy.

Comment: If the expansion of the universe is accelerating, shouldn’t we conclude that dark energy increases with distance? Something like the Hubble relation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual model says that dark energy is distributed uniformly around all the universe and as you probably know it expands the universe with him so it stays distributing uniformly, there are no clouds or irregular forms because that wouldn't explain the actual universe model. Maybe in the future that change.

Comment: Can I imagine that dark energy Is also in my room?